# How to replace "-" with empty space when columns are null in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, select, string-concatenation

Here I am having below Linq query which has employee duration column. How can I remove "-" when `StartDate` or `EndDate` is null. I want "-" only when both are not null.

```
var query = from r in db.Employee 
            select new 
            {
                Name = r.Name,
                EmployeeDuration = r.StartDate +" - "+ r.EndDate
            }
```

Comment: can you have an end date without a start date?

Comment: Also can both dates be null? What is the expected output in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a conditional operator.

```
var query = from r in db.Employee 
        select new 
        {
            Name = r.Name,
            EmployeeDuration = r.StartDate != null && r.EndDate != null 
                ? r.StartDate + " - " + r.EndDate
                : r.StartDate ?? r.EndDate
        }
```

*Output*

```
When nothing is null   = 18.01.2017 18:00 - 18.01.2017 19:00
When StartDate is null = 18.01.2017 19:00
When EndDate is null   = 18.01.2017 18:00
```

Or another approach would be this.

```
var query = from r in db.Employee 
        select new 
        {
            Name = r.Name,
            EmployeeDuration = 
                (r.StartDate ?? "?") +
                " - " +
                (r.EndDate ?? "?")
        }
```

*Output*

```
When nothing is null   = 18.01.2017 18:00 - 18.01.2017 19:00
When StartDate is null = ? - 18.01.2017 19:00
When EndDate is null   = 18.01.2017 18:00 - ?
```

Comment: You can simplify the last line to `r.StartDate ?? r.EndDate`

Answer (score 0):

```
EmployeeDuration = r.StartDate != null && r.EndDate != null ? r.StartDate + " - " + r.EndDate : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from employee in db.Employee 
            let areDatesNull = employee.StartDate == null
                            || employee.EndDate == null
            let duration = areDatesNull
                         ? ""
                         : $"{employee.StartDate} - {employee.EndDate}"
            select new 
            {
                Name = employee.Name,
                EmployeeDuration = duration
            }
```

Comment: @DavidG Oh, I see. Fixed.

Comment: The empty string still needs a value, for example: `$"{employee.StartDate ??
 employee.EndDate}"`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var query = from r in db.Employee
    select new
    {
        Name = r.Name
        ,
        EmployeeDuration =
        r.StartDate + ((r.StartDate == null || r.EndDate == null) ? string.Empty : " - ") + r.EndDate
    };
```